# ISO 8601 timestamps C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two `std::vector<string>'s` both with ISO 8601 timestamps where vector A maps to a number and Vector B maps to a headline

A is mapped with

```
 typedef pair<string,string> Key;   //<name,timestamp>
 typedef map< Key, double> Map;     //number
 Map pair_map;
```

B is mapped with

```
 map<string,string> Map2; //<headline,timestamp>
```

Then I have a third map that goes from headline to name

```
 map<string,string> Map3; //<headline,name>
```

essentially what I am trying to do is get the data that Vector A maps to at the time stamp of vector B. 
The Problem I am having is Vector A has iso time stamps in the following format where the seconds are always zero,

```
2012-02-25 06:09:00
2012-02-25 06:10:00
```

Vector B has it in with seconds

```
2012-02-25 06:09:32
2012-02-25 06:09:38
2012-02-25 06:09:51
```

What would be the best way to map Vector A to Vector B?

My two guesses at the best approach would be to round the second's down of Vector B, or Take some sort of weighted Average before and after i.e. `2012-02-25 06:09:00` and `2012-02-25 06:10:00.` What would be the best approach and how can I implement it?

Comment: Just compare the initial part, up to and including the minutes.

Comment: @KerrekSB that would be sort of liked rounded the seconds down to 00, how can I do that?

Comment: What is the type of your vector?

Comment: Well, for each pair of strings you can simply say `s1.compare(0, 16, s2, 0, 16)` to compare the first sixteen characters. But perhaps you want to compose a binary search around that idea. Are your vectors sorted?

Comment: Vector A is sorted , Vector B isn't

Comment: *vector A maps to a number* - What does that mean, precisely?

Comment: @Robᵩ: The OP also says she has *sets* of vectors. Who knows...

Comment: I updated it a bit to answer questions because of my stupidity but what Kerrerk SB posted should work Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should make yourself a comparison functor that only compares the strings up to the minute, i.e. the first sixteen digits:

```
#include <string>

struct isotimecomp
{
    // models "s1 < s2" for ISO time stamps
    bool operator()(std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2) const
    {
        return s1.compare(0, 16, s2, 0, 16) < 0;
    }
};
```

Now you can use that in any which way. For example, you can make an associative container keyed on timestamps:

```
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string>, isotimecomp> timestamp_data;
```

Or you can make a sorted vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> v;

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), isotimecomp());
```

Then you can do binary search on the vector:

```
std::string str = "2012-02-25 06:09:00";
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), str, isotimecomp());
```

Or you can use `find_if` on the vector, but you need a different predicate:

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&str](std::string const & s) -> bool
                       { return str.compare(0, 16, s, 0, 16) == 0;} );
```

Comment: @pyCthon: Oh, sorry, `find` doesn't quite work the way I portayed it. It needs its own, special predicate, and it should be `find_if`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/445H6nwz here the error and ah i will try find_if right now thanks!